# Cannot install typings (missing script: typings)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I tried to install typings in my angular 2 project by adding following lines in my package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js --global"
   }
```

Package.json:

```
      {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "name": "opengamelistwebapp",
        "private": true,
        "dependencies": {
          "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
          "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",

          "core-js": "^2.4.1",
          "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
          "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
          "systemjs": "^0.19.37",
          "typings": "^1.3.2",
          "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "gulp": "^3.9.1",
          "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
          "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
          "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
          "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
          "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
          "typescript": "^1.8.10"
        }
        ,
        "scripts": {
          "postinstall": "typings install dt~core-js --global"
        }
      }
```

Typings dosen't get installed and I tried another medthod by typing following command in CMD in the project root directory:
     npm run typings install

I was able to see following logs in the npm-debug.log

```
  0 info it worked if it ends with ok
  1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  1 verbose cli 'C:\\Users\\logukis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
  1 verbose cli   'run',
  1 verbose cli   'typings',
  1 verbose cli   'install' ]
  2 info using npm@4.1.2
  3 info using node@v6.9.4
  4 verbose stack Error: missing script: typings
  4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
  4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
  4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:356:5
  4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:320:45)
  4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:354:3)
  4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:124:5)
  4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:295:20)
  4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\logukis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
  4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:365:13)
  5 verbose cwd E:\Angular2\Packt Examples Chapterwise\Packt LocalExamples\Chapter1Try2\src\Chapter1Try2
  6 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
  7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\logukis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "typings" "install"
  8 error node v6.9.4
  9 error npm  v4.1.2
  10 error missing script: typings
  11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
  11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
  12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How do I install typings in my project? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you tried to simply install them through npm as global?
`npm install typings --global`